# Java Graphics, Graphics panel and Buttons Panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border-layout

I am trying to create a Frame that has a graphics panel on the top portion (through a  Layout) and a buttons / labels panel underneath it in the same frame. So far I seemed to have been able to get both of them onto the same frame but the Graphics panel is very small compared to the buttons / labels panel... I cant post photos but its almost as if the size was (400,10) for the Graphics panel and (400,290) for the Buttons / Labels panel.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

 public class DoNotEnterSign extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(0,0,50,50);
    }}




public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new DoNotEnterSign();
            panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            panel.setSize(100,100);
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            JButton test = new JButton("Testing");
            panel2.add(test);
            frame2.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame2.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame2.setSize(400,300);
            frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just override `getPreferedSize()` method of your `DoNotEnterSign` class instead of using `setSize(100,100);`. Because according to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html) it works only without layout manager:

> Set the size of the component measured in pixels. The two int
>   arguments specify width and height, in that order. Use these methods
>   to size a component when you are not using a layout manager.

Add next to your `DoNotEnterSign` :

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(100,100);
}
```

[image]